# Xcode Using Exponents

Tags: xcode, numbers, division, exponent

This is probably a simple question, but I a variable "side" to be divided by the square of the variable "curNum". Currently, my code for this looks like

```
side = inputNum/(curNum^2);
```

However, this gives me the error "Invalid operands to binary ^" How can I successfully use exponents?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try

```
pow(curNum, 2)
```

Should work......